# Signature of Bilinear Form.

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be the vector space $M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$, and let $B : V × V → \mathbb{R}$ be the bilinear form $B(X,Y)$ = tr$(XY^T)$. Calculate the signature of $B$.
Here, tr means the trace of the matrix.

I'm stuck here as I was only able to conclude that this is a symmetric bilinear form (correct me if I'm wrong), then how to proceed after this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of trace and product of matrices, if $x_i$ denotes the $i$th row of a matrix $X$, then
$${\rm tr}(XX^T)\ =\ \sum_i x_i{x_i}^T\ =\ \sum_i\|{x_i}^T\|^2\ >\ 0$$
unless each $x_i=0$.
Here $\|v\|^2=\sum_jv_j^2$ is the square of the Euclidean norm of vector $v$.

By the way, if you calculated entrywise, you'd obtain
$${\rm tr}(XY^T)\ =\ \sum_{i,j}x_{i,j}y_{i,j}$$
which is just the usual inner product on the space of *flattened* (vectorized) matrices (utilizing the linear isomorphism $M_{m,n}(\Bbb R)\cong\Bbb R^{m\cdot n}$).

Comment: So is the signature (n,0) where n = dimension of $V$ ?

Comment: Now $V=M_{n,n}(\Bbb R)$ which has dimension $n^2$, but yes, it's positive definite.

Comment: Okay so I can directly say that it has signature (n,0) where $n^2$ = dim($V$)

Comment: No. It has signature $(n^2,0)$ because $n^2=\dim V$.

Comment: Oh okay, I was a little confused as I earlier wrote that the signature is (dim$V$,$0$) but I used $'n'$ to represent it which I didn't check that is already used in the matrix.

Comment: I have a doubt, how can I find an orthogonal basis for this bilinear form?

Comment: Maybe reread the last paragraph of my answer.